# Работа с консолью браузера вкладка network

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Как вытащить информацию из консоли хрома с вкладки network не используя browsermob-proxy ?
Нужно считывать response

Comment: Уточните вопрос - причём здесь java?

Comment: для расширений chromium есть API у devtools, покопать нужно, возможно написать такое расширение, а оно уже сможет интегрироваться с чем-то внешним. второе - в хроме есть какая-то система remote debugging. третье - почему именно оттуда, это единственный сниффер на планете, что ли? есть снифферы других уровней

Comment: Есть автотесты на java  с использованием selenium , появилась необходимость обрабатывать информацию из 
консоль браузера->network->response

Comment: Пусть браузер ходит на сайт через вашу проксю, которая читает трафик вдоль и поперек.

Comment: через прокси не подходит решение
или без прокси это в целом невозможно?